# Delete Specific Rows from a CSV File Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, import-csv, powershell-5.1, export-csv, where-object

The script that I put together does gather the results I need, but I was hoping to utilize a cleaner string.

After I gather all the needed information, I export the results to a csv file. There are three specific rows I would like to remove, so I re-import the csv file and delete those rows. This is the string I am currently utilizing:

```
#Remove Unneeded Users
import-csv .\LDAPCrossWalkTable.csv | Where-Object "User ID" -ne 'test' | Where-Object "User ID" -ne 'process' | Where-Object "User ID" -ne 'app' | export-csv .\LDAPCrossWalkTableFinal.csv -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

Is there a way to use the Where-Object cmdlet one time by using the -or operator rather than pipe 3 separate times? I just can't figure out the correct syntax. Any input it greatly appreciated! Thanks!

UPDATE: Thank you, Olaf, for the prompt response and multiple options! I decided to proceed with this string:

```
import-csv .\LDAPCrossWalkTable.csv | Where-Object {$_.'User ID' -notin 'test', 'process', 'app'} | export-csv .\LDAPCrossWalkTableFinal.csv -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to combine more than one filter in one `Where-Object`. And you can apply this filter before you export your results to a CSV file

```
Where-Object {
$_.'User ID' -ne 'test' -and
$_.'User ID' -ne 'process' -and 
$_.'User ID' -ne 'app'
}
```

As pointed out by the comment of @Santiago Squarzon ... and alternative to having multiple `-ne` would be to use `-notin`.

```
Where-Object {
    $_.'User ID' -notin 'test', 'process', 'app'
}
```

... or ... as suggested like this:

```
Where-Object 'User ID' -notin 'test', 'process', 'app'
```

A third way recommended by @Theo would be top use regex like this:

```
Where-Object 'User ID' -notmatch '\b(test|process|app)\b'
```

or like this if it should be a full match

```
Where-Object 'User ID' -notmatch '^(test|process|app)$'
```

Now you have plenty of options to choose from. ;-)

Comment: Or with regex `Where-Object {$_.'User ID' -notmatch '\b(test|process|app)\b' }`. You can change the first `\b` into `^` and the last `\b` into `$` if there should be a full match

Comment: Ah ... I see what you mean ... added.  Thanks.